# Complex Date Range

Tags: oracle, date, range, between

I'm working on the following query and cant figure out the final piece of it. I need my query to give me a result set between the previous business and the previous business day minus (-) 28 days. (e.g. date range between 10/28/2015 and 10/28/2015 -28) The query that I wrote so far is only giving me the -28th day (09/30/2015) and NOT a range in between the previous business day and the previous business day -28. My research shows a couple of different ways of doing it and so far none have worked for me.

```
SELECT SMBL, SUM(NET_FLOWS/1000000.00) 
FROM HISTORY
WHERE DATE - 28 = DATE AND DATE = TO_DATE('10282015','MMDDYYYY') 
AND SYMBOL IN ('AAA','BBB')
GROUP BY SMBL
```

Comment: What about `WHERE DATE between TO_DATE('10282015','MMDDYYYY') - 28 and  TO_DATE('10282015','MMDDYYYY')` ?  BETWEEN is inclusive.

Comment: How can DATE-28=DATE ever resolve to TRUE?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber yes it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MichaelBroughton this is the calculation that my firm is using. I know what you mean however its part of my testing and I def needed to have it in that specific way.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton kind of off topic however I just found out that  my result set should show the top 10 values in the Net_flows  instead of the specific SYMBOL that I'm looking for in this query. Would you be able to help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Top ten based on what criteria? top ten SMBL ordered by SUM(NETFLOWS/10000000.00)?

Comment: @MichaelBroughton The Net_Flows is a dollar amount. I basically need the top 10 Sum values of the Net_Flows. The SYMBOL at that point will obviously vary.

Comment: Basically - you write your query to return the results in the order you want then you wrap that query in brackets and SELECT * FROM (your_query) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 to get the top ten. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858325/oracle-top-n-ordered-rows

Comment: @MichaelBroughton  is the ROWNUM giving me the top 10 lines or the top 10 values. My result set seems to be the top 10 lines instead of the top 10 dollar values that I'm looking for.

Comment: That;s why you need to order the lines first so that the top ten lines ARE the top ten values.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton That makes sense. I just wast sure if there was another way of doing it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll look it the rest of it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, date ranges are easy using BETWEEN, so you do the quick solution:

```
WHERE DATE BETWEEN (SYSDATE-28) and (SYSDATE-1)
```

Then you realize your dates have time components, so to include all of yesterday and all of day-28 you need to:

```
WHERE DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-28 
AND   DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Then I look at your rule "previous BUSINESS day" and ask - what are your business days? On a Monday to go up to the previous Friday? Or Saturday? Or are you a 7-day-a-week business? How about statutory holidays? And is it 28 CALENDAR days back? Or 28 BUSINESS days?

Ahh business rules. The devil is always in those details....

Comment: to answer a few of your questions. We are a Mon-Fri (5 Business Day) firm. Therefore if its a monday then we would revert to the friday business date for data. The reason why I'm using 28 days is because we are using 4 week date range for our calculations therefore that is where the 28 days are coming from. Your query of sysdate-28 is off by a little because my starting point is the previous business date not the current. However with a simple addition of a day e.g. sysdate - 29, the query worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, business -1 then - 28. I missed the extra day. Like I said... it's always the little details that trip you up :-)